# How do I execute code once in a 5 minute in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, countdowntimer

I want to call an API when user takes a screen. But it should be sent only one request in 5 minute. If user took the same screen before 5 minute of first API request sent, it should not sent the second API call.
If user took the same page after 5 minute of previous API request, it should made a request.

Answer (score 1):

If you instanciate a Date() object it will represent the date and time at the instaciation - i.e. "now".

1. Create a field of type Date storing the time of last access.
2. Initilize this field to some time in the past (say the day before "now").
3. Upon an request: Compare this date to the date of last access (see API documentation of how to compare dates). If the difference is large, update the date of last access to the current date/time.

Comment: `distantPast` is a good value to use in step 2